# Tab Dropdown selection how to show

Tags: navigation, tabs, dropdown, selection

[Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQHX8.png)

I have this horizontal nav design, where once you select an item from the more dropdown it is displayed as shown in the image. Any reference for any library or example which I can share with my dev team so they can implement this.

I tried searching online but could not find any option.